# Require one of two fields to be filled (either/or) in custom web form validate.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

So, I have these two form fields. Currently they are both 'required' as you may see. I am using standard `validate.js` the problem is I would like to change this to not be default required for each, but **only the user has to do one; so basically either or should be required.** Any approach ideas?

```
<label class="filebutton">
    <span id="select">Select File</span><span><input name="Text1" type="file"  id="upload" required></span>
</label>

<textarea class="form-control" name="Text2" rows="5" id="word_count" placeholder="What would you do with your 25th hour? [100 words max]" required></textarea>

<em>Total word count:</em> <span id="display_count">0</span> <em>words.</em> <em>Words left:</em> <span id="word_left">100</span>
<br>
```

**attempt 1.)**

```
function validateForm(){
    var value1 = document.getElementById('upload').value;
    var value2 = document.getElementById('word_count').value;
    if( value1 != "" || value2 != "" ) {
        return true;    
    }
    alert("You must enter a value");
    return false;
}
```

**attempt 2.)**

```
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        text1: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".phone-group"]
        },
        text2: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".phone-group"]
        }
    }
});
```